# multi threading in Python using text file

Tags: python, multithreading

let's say am having text list containing

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
hhh
iii
jjj
kkk
lll
mmm
nnn
ooo
ppp
qqq
rrr
sss
ttt
uuu
```

I want to write code to get 5 lines each time and apply specific function on them
this one suppose to get 5 lines each time and execute the function message on them

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
def message(msg):
    print msg
    time.sleep(2)

file=open("x.txt","r")
for i in range(5):
    line=file.readline(i)
    message(line)
```

But it doesn't seem to work well. One othher thing is how to make it multithreaded using `thread` module.

Comment: What do you mean, it does not work well? Have you tried implementing multithreading yourself?

Comment: Do you really need multi-thread? Why can't you just use the [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in?

Comment: Please be more specific about the phenomenon you observe and the results you'd like to achieve and describe the differences between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're looking for, but here's some basic code to get you going. (assumes that `testdata` is a list containing the lines you provided above)

```
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

def send_message(msg): 
    print msg
    sleep(2)

jobs = []
for datum in testdata: 
    proc = Thread(target=send_msg, args=(datum,))
    jobs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
```

As to divvying it up into 5s or whatever, you can tweak that to suit your needs.